# Enlarging a mediaElement

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have a media element in my website. Styled [like so](http://dorienherremans.com/imma/demo):

I would like to make the entire element bigger. I have tried enlarging the div's but it's not changing it. Would it be possible to "zoom" in on it in some way, so the player shows bigger?

Comment: Show us an example...
You want to make only the player bigger, or you want to make the video frame bigger as well?

Comment: Please see the link in my question. I would like the doom the whole player bar

Comment: Have you tried to add `style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"` to your audio tag? (#player2) I think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once the option "autosizeProgress" is by default set to true, any style changes on the player will be overlaid. So if you want to make more customizations on your player I recommend you to change this option to 'false'.

In order to set the player to full page width (responsive) you need to add to your `<audio>` or `<video>` this style: `style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"`